# ManagedBass Wasapi dll UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, wasapi

I have to retrieve the device output data to create a stream with ManagedBass.Wasapi.dll, but an error is returned despite having copied the basswasapi.dll to the system32 folder and to the app's debug folder.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void BtnWasapi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var device = BassWasapi.CurrentDevice;
}
```

I installed the dll with:

> Install-Package ManagedBass.Wasapi -Version 2.0.0

The error is:

> Attempted to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

How can BassWasapi work?

Thanks in advance.